# Is it possible to create a ListView background/selector for every theme?

Tags: android, listview, android-styles

Suppose I have a dark theme and a light theme and I want to have different listview selector/background depending upon my theme. I know its not possible via drawable as drawable cannot reference colours unless they are explicitly specified.

Is it possible to create a custom listview style for every theme?

Comment: Yes you can apply two different styles dynamically. Simple define your style into the style.xml and using code you can change it accordingly.

Comment: How? Do I change the listview selector when I switch themes?